# touchmove drawing two lines instead of one on canvas

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a PhoneGap application with jQuery Mobile UI framework. I need a page where users will be able to draw stuff on the screen. I used [this](http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/html5-canvas-paint-app-for-iphone/) for reference and it works great in Ripple Emulator. However, on my actual device, a Nexus 4, instead of one line per touchmove, I get two lines. Is there something wrong with what I am doing?

**EDIT:** I found a similar problem reported in github. It seems to be the problem with Android's browser. The two lines were due to overlapping canvas elements. The only solution is to have canvas size less than 256px. Here's the link:
 https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5107

Here's my code

```
// start canvas code

var canvas = null; //canvas object
var context = null; //canvas's context object
var clearBtn = null; //clear button object
var buttonDown = false;

function captureDraw(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    clearBtn = document.getElementById('clearBtn');

    setCanvasDimension();
    initializeEvents();

    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

function setCanvasDimension() {
  //canvas.width = 300; 
  // canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  // canvas.height = window.innerHeight; //setting the height of the canvas
}

function initializeEvents() {
  canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', startPaint, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', continuePaint, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchend', stopPaint, false);

  clearBtn.addEventListener('touchend', clearCanvas,false);
}

function clearCanvas() {
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

function startPaint(evt) {
  if(!buttonDown)
  {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(evt.touches[0].pageX, evt.touches[0].pageY);
    buttonDown = true;
  }
  evt.preventDefault();
}

function continuePaint(evt) {
  if(buttonDown)
  {
    context.lineTo(evt.touches[0].pageX,evt.touches[0].pageY);
    context.stroke();
  }
}

function stopPaint() {
  buttonDown = false;
}

// end canvas code
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an actual answer, but I found out that this is a known bug since Android 4.1.1. There have been many solutions like overriding `offset-x: visible` to the parent div of the canvas element, but it didn't work for me. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35474 for more information.

Other solution is keeping your canvas size below 256px. This is certainly a weird bug!